# How to setting up right "plugins" folder in airflow?

Tags: airflow

I'm using airflow, and I want to import some plugins for my dags
The problem get into the play: when I'm trying to use them, follow by:

```py
from dags_folder.plugins import fetchingData
```

I get this error

```
Module name "dags_folder" not found!
```

([here is my layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgCsm.png))

I've setting up with the airflow.cfg, but it doesn't work!
notes: I'm using conda-env

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the folder `dags_folder` to python path:

```bash
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/path/to/dags_folder
```

then you could import `fetchingData` from `plugins`:

```py
from plugins import fetchingData
```

(if you want to import it from `dags_folder.plugins`, you need to add the parent folder of `dags_folder` to the python path).

If you need this plugin in one module, you can add the plugins package to python path pragmatically:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/dags_folder")
from plugins import fetchingData
```